# Sample Temple diaspora rabbinic responsum

Tags: beis-hamikdash, responsa

Are there any books which present, in the traditional rabbinic responsum format, questions that could or would arise throughout temple life (or just the temple)? [And thus answer them based on traditional sources.]

Comment: I remember seeing such but I do not remember the name. I have also seen articles written as if being taught to kohanim who are coming to the Bais Hamikdash just after the Mashiach arrives and while the temple is being set up.